# How to delete from mysql using bootstrap modal?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to delete accounts according to the selection of a drop down list.

This is my markup for the `form` -

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select class="form-control" size="8" id="userName" name="userName">
        <option value="9" data-userId="uid9">dilani</option>
        <option value="6" data-userId="uid6">kamala</option>
        <option value="12" data-userId="uid12">senudhi</option>
        <option value="2" data-userId="uid2">testuser</option>
        <option value="4" data-userId="uid4">tharanga</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Terminate</button>
    <br>
</form>
```

In `PHP`, I am checking an user is submitting the form and have selected an username from dropdown before delete the account.

My `PHP` code is something like this -

```
// Check for a form submission:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
    // Check for username is selected from dropdown list: 
    if (isset($_POST['userName'])) {
        $userid = $_POST['userName'];               

        //echo $userid; 
        // my delete query ---

    } else {
        $error_msg .= ' You didn\' select either username or domain name to Terminate.';
    }
}
```

My problem is, If the form have submitted successfully then I need to display a conformation dialog box before to delete the account.

I tried it `javascript` `onsubmit` but its not working for me. As soon as I click on Terminate button the confirmation is display ignoring the selection of dropdown. That mean I don't need to select an item from username list to get this work.

This is how I checked it -

```
<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="return confirm('are you sure?')">
```

Can anybody guide me to do this using `Bootstrap` modal?

Thank You.

Comment: if that submit going through ajax, then you can use the beforeSend function, so in that you can call the bootstrap modal

Comment: @amtest, Since I am not good in javascript or jquery, Can you explain it with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Capture the form on submit, toss out a confirm box. Return true if they click Yes, return false if they click No.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this user?')){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Ohgodwhy, I tried it with your code. But I can not get a confire box

Answer (score 0):

Either you can submit via ajax, or if you need to just confirm that you can use something like

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input id="btn" type="button" value="Go"/>
</form>

$(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    if (confirm("Click OK to continue?")){
      $('form#target').submit();
    } else {
      //return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: amtest, Can we use bootstrap modal regarding this?

Comment: yes, if its true then you call the bootstrap modal, like 
  $('#dialog').modal('show'); , if you get more about that modal, read this http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals